# Problem with changing order of integration in spherical coordinates

Tags: multiple-integral, spherical-coordinates

The problem I am dealing with most likely boils down to a shorter one stated at the end of this text. Just in case I am mistaken about it, I am providing full context. You may skip to the end.

The following is a problem from exercise 13.6 of Calculus and Analytic Geometry by George B. Thomas

> Let $D$ be the region in Exercise 11. Set up the triple integrals in spherical coordinates that give the volume of $D$ using the following orders of integration:
> a) $d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta$ b) $d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta$

Said $D$ is the region bounded below by the plane $z=0$, above by the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$, and on the sides by the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$. Anyway I seek the answer to 31b which according to the solution is

$$ \int_0 ^{2\pi} \int _0^2 \int_0 ^{\pi/6} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta \ + \int_0 ^{2\pi}\int_1^2 \int _{\pi/6} ^{\arcsin{1/ \rho}} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta $$

But it doesn't quite add up, because it has to yield the same number as 31a; and 11abc for that matter, because Exercise 11 is the very same problem in cylindrical coordinates. All of which (31a included) yielded to $(8/3 - \sqrt3) 2\pi$ but 31b yields to $(8/3 - \sqrt3 -1/2\sqrt{3}) 2\pi$, even [according to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5DSin%5Bz%5D%2C%7Bz%2C0%2CDivide%5B%CF%80%2C6%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C2%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5DSin%5Bz%5D%2C%7Bz%2CDivide%5B%CF%80%2C6%5D%2CArcSin%5BDivide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5D%7D%2C%7Bx%2C1%2C2%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C2%CF%80%7D%5D).

**Observations:**

Further inspection has led me to compare the answers of 31a and 31b. 31b's was stated above, 31a's is as following

$$ \int_0 ^{2\pi} \int_0 ^{\pi/6} \int _0^2 \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta \ + \int_0 ^{2\pi}\int _{\pi/6} ^{\pi/2} \int_0 ^{\csc \phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta $$

Notice how the limits in the first triple integral of both sums are unaffected by the change in order. That's because they correspond to the volume of the single-napped spherical cone, a shape that can be described via constant spherical coordinates. Indeed, those two integrals yield the same numerical value.

The crux of the problem is then that two integrals

$$ \int_0 ^{2\pi}\int _{\pi/6} ^{\pi/2} \int_0 ^{\csc \phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\rho\ d\phi\ d\theta \ \ \ \text{and} \ \int_0 ^{2\pi}\int_1^2 \int _{\pi/6} ^{\arcsin{1/ \rho}} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta $$

do not equate. The change of limits make perfect sense to me, so why do they still not equate? I seek aid to reason of it.

Comment: Should the upper $\rho$ limit of the left integral be $\csc(\phi)$ rather than $\csc(\rho)$ ?

Comment: The two regions of integration are not the same. If you change the lower $\rho$-limit of the left integral to $\rho=1$, then they are the same

Comment: @RonnyLandsverk Oh, yes sir! I'll fix it right away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integral for $31$b is not correct. It misses part of the volume. The given solution as per you is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0 ^{2\pi} \int _0^2 \int_0 ^{\pi/6} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta~$ + $ \displaystyle \int_0 ^{2\pi}\int_1^2 \int _{\pi/6} ^{\arcsin{(1/ \rho)}} \rho^2 \sin\phi\ d\phi\ d\rho\ d\theta$

but it misses the volume for $~0 \le \rho \le 1$ and $\pi/6 \le \phi \le \pi/2$. So if you add the below, it will all match.

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/2} \rho^2 \sin\phi ~d\phi ~d\rho~ d\theta$

An easier way to represent in the order $~d\phi ~ d\rho ~ d\theta~$ is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \rho^2 \sin\phi ~d\phi ~d\rho~ d\theta ~ + $

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_1^2 \int_0^{\arcsin(1/\rho)} \rho^2 \sin\phi ~d\phi ~d\rho ~d\theta$

Comment: Aaaaaa... how could I have missed that! And your solution, aah just... wonderful!!! Thank you, kind sir

Comment: you are welcome!